# Is there a Problem with the "<" operator?

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

I actually do not like the concept of splitting the code into lots and lots of contracts.

I basically wrote one crowed sale contract that handles tiers. I do not need time limits.

Everything works fine. But If I send 100000000000000000 WEI (which is the max amount you can send in one transaction) after the second time it jumps into `if(weiRaised.add(weiAmount) > cap[currentTier])` which makes no  sense because twice 100000000000000000 WEI is exactly the `cap[2]`. Thus result in `if(100000000000000000 + 100000000000000000 > 200000000000000000)` which should be `FALSE`. I'm little confused.

In the end - it does not really matter because it just produces two `0` value transactions. Because `overFunded = 0`. But anyway. Seems awkward.

In short it looks like (I know it seems long but it's pretty straight forward and easy. I only put in the relevant function. Working code here:

```
contract Crowdsale{
using SafeMath for uint256;

// The token being sold
Token public token;

// address where funds are collected
address public wallet;

// how many token units a buyer gets per wei in each tier
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public rate;

// max cap in eacht tier
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public cap;

// the current tier we are in
uint256 public currentTier;

// amount of token raised in "wei"
uint256 public tokenRaised  = 0;

// amount of raised money in wei
uint256 public weiRaised    = 0;

event TokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed 
beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

function Crowdsale(address _wallet, IWToken _token) public {
require(_wallet != address(0));
require(_token  != address(0));

/* HERE THE VARIABLES GET INIT */
// set token address
token = _token;
owner = msg.sender;

// set rates
rate[1] = 23000;
rate[2] = 22000;
rate[3] = 21000;
rate[4] = 20000;

// set caps in Wei
cap[1] = 100000000000000000;
cap[2] = 200000000000000000;
cap[3] = 300000000000000000;
cap[4] = 1000000000000000000;

// the current tier
currentTier = 1;

wallet = _wallet;
/* INIT DONE */

}

// token purchase function
function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
require(beneficiary != address(0));
require(!stopped);
require(msg.value <= 100000000000000000);
require(msg.value > 0);

uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

uint256 tokens;

// in case that the cap is exceeded
if(weiRaised.add(weiAmount) > cap[currentTier]){

  // split the fund
  uint256 overFunded     = weiRaised.add(weiAmount).sub(cap[currentTier]);
  weiAmount              = msg.value.sub(overFunded);

  // update state
  // calculate token amount to be created
  tokens        = weiAmount.mul(rate[currentTier]);
  weiRaised     = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
  tokenRaised   = tokenRaised.add(tokens);

  // first fraction of token
  token.ICOmint(beneficiary, tokens);
  TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);
  forwardFunds(weiAmount);

  // go into next tier
  currentTier = currentTier+1;

  if(currentTier > 4){
    // Refund overspend wei
    msg.sender.transfer(overFunded);

    // stop token sale
    stopped = true;
    } else {
     // fund the remaining
     tokens        = overFunded.mul(rate[currentTier]);
     weiRaised     = weiRaised.add(overFunded);
     tokenRaised   = tokenRaised.add(tokens);

     // second fraction of token
     token.ICOmint(beneficiary, tokens);
     TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, overFunded, tokens);
     forwardFunds(overFunded);
   }

   } else {
    // calculate token amount to be created
    tokens        = weiAmount.mul(rate[currentTier]);
    weiRaised     = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
    tokenRaised   = tokenRaised.add(tokens);

    token.ICOmint(beneficiary, tokens);
    TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);
    forwardFunds(msg.value);
  }
}

function forwardFunds(uint256 _amount) internal {
  wallet.transfer(_amount);
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Can you post a set of code that compiles? (If the whole contract is too big, then a subset that compiles is probably as good.) Might be easier for others to play around with it that way.

Comment: I’d recommend using the “ether” keyword instead of using numbers with so many zeroes, it will make it easier for you to spot a problem. Or doing 1 ** (10 ** 18) instead.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks
**Compiling and working copy:**
https://gist.github.com/kn1g/2b82ad2678e75aca405483dc45a804bb

I simplified everything a little bit. All **imported contracts** are the **standard Zeppelin contacts**. Does this help?

Comment: @pabloruiz55 that would be more readable but should be the same in the end...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the contract is deployed we have

```
currentTier = 1
weiRaised = 0
cap[currentTier] = 100000000000000000
```

---

When the first payment of `100000000000000000` is sent we have

```
weiAmount = 100000000000000000
weiRaised.add(weiAmount) = 100000000000000000
cap[currentTier] = 100000000000000000
```

Then `weiRaised.add(weiAmount) > cap[currentTier]` is false. Only `weiRaised` is updated, `currentTier` remain unchanged

```
weiRaised = 100000000000000000
```

---

When the second payment of `100000000000000000` is sent we will have

```
weiAmount = 100000000000000000
weiRaised.add(weiAmount) = 200000000000000000
currentTier = 1
cap[currentTier] = 100000000000000000
```

And then `weiRaised.add(weiAmount) > cap[currentTier]` is true (remember `currentTier` was never modified). Inside the branch the variables will updated to

```
overFunded = 100000000000000000
weiAmount = 0
weiRaised = 100000000000000000
currentTier = 2
```

The `overFunded` is returned to the sender. Only `currentTier` is updated and events are triggered with 0 value. It is pretty much like this transaction never happened.

I strongly suggest to separate your logic into:

- Tiers management
- Payment processing

And to add unit test for edge case, ie when switching tiers.

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean with separating the logic and unit test for edge case?

Comment: Your function `buyTokens` is quite large, it is better to separate some functionality into smallers function, that are simpler to debug/test. For example `getRemainingTierCap`, `updateCurrentTier` , `processPayment`, etc.